# Getting error in bundle.js angular universal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal, angular-ssr

My angular build is throwing this in web browser. `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' in bundle.js`

I am running this command `npm run dev:ssr`, and it generates no error.

But when I browse the application it displays the error. I tried with `ng serve --aot` but the application is configured to be run only with `npm run dev:ssr`.
From where I can debug so I can fix this syntax error.

Edit: More Information
`npm run build` makes the bundle.js with correct data in dist/browser. So I think it is some debug feature?

Answer (score -1):

Your browser is looking for `bundle.js` which is available but your server is sending some other startup file (e.g. `index.html`) which itself starts with new HTML tag (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc.) .

So when javascript parses your `bundle.js` file, it was looking for expression (e.g. methods, function body of typescript etc.), but it got new HTML start tag `<`. This scenario resulted in `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`.

So can you check source of your page (under `Sources` section) in browser if `bundle.js` has any html tag included. If that is case, you may need change your routing so that either `bundle.js` will be loaded or other startup file will gets loaded.

Comment: I understand what it is, thank you for translating it. What I am looking for is, a solution, to track and fix this.

Comment: `From where I can debug so I can fix this syntax error.` this is what you have asked. Modify your question & share some more details so that anyone can see you are looking for solution & not just direction where to start debugging. Thanks